# Does c# behave differently in function parameter Implicit conversions then direct implicit conversion

Tags: c#

when I am writing in c# (on .net 5) the following code

```
public class Apple
{
    public int weight { get; set; }
    public Apple(int w)
    {
       weight = w;
    }

    public bool Equals(Apple other)
    {
        return ((other != null) &&(weight == other.weight));
    }
}
```

in the main function, I declare

```
Apple a1 = new Apple(10);
Object a2 = new Apple(10);
```

when I run afterwards the following code
`Console.WriteLine(a1.Equals(a2));`
it will compile and run and return "false" (even though they are the same).

but writing this code `a1 = a2;` will get a compiler error.

> [Error    CS0266](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0266?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0266))  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Apple'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

can anyone explain what is the difference?

Comment: `a1` is of type `Apple`, `a2` is object, meaning it could be anything. `a1=a2` is a runtime assigment, compiler cannot guarantee you're atributing an Apple to a `a1`, so you have to cast it like `a1=(Apple)a2`

Comment: I understood that. the question is why the function is not returning the same error.
I tried to make it as clear as I could in the heading.
the function is returning a wrong result also.

Comment: Note that `a1.Equals(a2)` is using a different overload (the one that get inherited from `object`) than the one you have written in your `Apple` class here

Comment: What @DavidG wrote. Object has methods and all types inherit from Object so your Apple type will also have those methods one of which is `bool Equals(object obj)`. That is the actual method you are calling in your code, not your overload. If you debug your code and put a break point in your overload you will see it is never reached.

Comment: yes I understood now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every object already has an `bool Equals(object? obj)` method, and you're calling that when you pass an `object` to your Equals.  Instead properly override the built-in Equals

```
public class Apple
{
    public int weight { get; set; }
    public Apple(int w)
    {
        weight = w;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj is Apple a )
        {
            return this.weight == a.weight;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(weight);
    }

}
```

Comment: The override should pass through to the original function which has the `Apple obj` parameter, also a good idea to implement `IEquatable<Apple>` and `==` operator. Otherwise even when you have an `Apple` object you will get casting.